# Get WebBrowsers parent control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

Ive been trying to get the parent of this WebBrowser control. Somehow i can't seem to find the right way of getting the parent. i thought it would work like this :

```
private void webtabItem1_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser Webr = (WebBrowser) sender;
    CloseableTabItem Tab = (CloseableTabItem) Webr.Parent);
    Tab.Header = e.Uri.Host;
}
```

It gives the error "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" on .Parent.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.button.parent%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) tells you can only access it as a object i tried but it doesn't seem to work.

I could get the child of the tab by means of .Content

```
WebBrowser Webr = (WebBrowser)Tab.Content;
```

It's probably not that hard just some stupid mistake of me.

Comment: CloseableTabItem Tab = (CloseableTabItem) Webr.Parent; bad parenthesis at the end

Comment: Lol that even more stupid as i thought thanks tho, sorry for wasting time ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is due to an extra parenthesis after `Parent`, try:

```
CloseableTabItem Tab = (CloseableTabItem)Webr.Parent;
```